# Let $S = \{1,2,...,n+1\},n\geq2$ and $T = \{(x,y,z)\in S^3 | x<z\ and\ y<z\}$. Find $|T|$

Tags: combinatorics

Let $S = \{1,2,...,n+1\},n\geq2$ and $T = \{(x,y,z)\in S^3 | x<z\ and\ y<z\}$. Find $|T|$

> Actually you have to show , by counting $|T|$ in two different ways,
>   that $\sum_{k=1}^nk^2=|T| = {{n+1}\choose2} + 2{n+1\choose3}$

. All I was able to do is to show that you can define a function $f:S\to\mathbb{N}$ such that $f(s) = (s-1)^2 + 2\sum^{n+1-s}_{i=1}(s+i-1) -(n+1-s)$ which basically shows for a given $s\in S$ in how many triplets in $T$ it is a coordinate (hope that makes sense). Then obviously $|T| = \sum_{s\in S}f(s)$, but this did not get me closer to proving the above question. Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The left hand side of the double-equality expression supposes that you have selected $z=k+1$ and then counts the $k$ options for each of $(x,y)$ for each case of $z$, to get 
$$|T|= \sum_{k=1}^{n}k^2$$

The right hand side of the expression requires that you count three ways of selecting from the ordered $S$ to get $(x,y,z)$, $(y,x,z)$ and $(x=y,z)$, the last case selecting only two values of course, to get

$$|T|={n+1 \choose 3}+{n+1 \choose 3}+{n+1 \choose 2}$$